# .NET WebBrowser: Retrieve all videos to play on any given web page

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, video

I am involved in an opportunity for which I have been tasked to write a "spider" application whose goal is to dynamically crawl a predefined set of web pages and/or specific URIs and retrieve as many videos as possible either playing on the page or scheduled to play on the page. The goal here is to collect advertising, which is generally not encrypted, so this is not a question about decrypting streamed content or anything in that direction.

We have attempted various solutions, e.g.:

- Employing a HTTP Session analysis tool like Fiddler and using a Fiddler extension I wrote to transmit any HTTP sessions that look like video (FLV, MPEG-4, various hints in the URL/headers/etc.) to a separate aggregator application via WCF;
- Scanning every single ASCII text file transmitted during the spidering session for URLs to video files, and investigating them/downloading them one at a time before transmitting them to the aggregator application;

etc.

Unfortunately the coverage with these solutions has been less than satisfactory; for some sites, we get absolutely none of the videos; other sites, we get some, and for very few sites we get all of them.

Especially frustrating are sites whose browser must be in focus for any videos to play, or sites where a "play" button must be clicked before any videos will load or play, or sites where the video content must be visible *AND* in focus before any videos will load or play, etc. It is not very efficient to run only a single spider per server to collect these videos.

As stated, we are using a C# .NET Winforms solution hosting a WebBrowser control. Perhaps there are better components out there? Any suggestions appreciated, though we would very much like to stay within the .NET world (third-party components that work well with .NET interop are fine obviously).

Thanks for any information!